# search, replace and regroup with regexp and php

Tags: php, regex, search, replace

I would like to search and replace some tags with regexp.

this is my starting string:

```html
<p>some bla bla bla</p>
<p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
<p class="normale">•bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
<p>other bla bla bla</p>
<p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
<p class="normale">•bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
<p>other bla bla bla</p>
```

and this is the result that I want

```html
<p>some bla bla bla</p>
<ul><li>bla bla and bla</li><li>bla bla and bla</li>
<li>bla bla and bla</li><li>bla bla and bla</li><li>bla bla and bla</li></ul>
<p>other bla bla bla</p>
<ul><li>bla bla and bla</li><li>bla bla and bla</li>
<li>bla bla and bla</li><li>bla bla and bla</li>
<li>other bla bla bla</li></ul>
```

**So I want to substitute all `<p>•` or `<p>&bull;` with `<li>` and `</p>` with `</li>` and regroup every group of `<li></li><li></li><li></li>` in `<ul></ul>`**

For now I have done some test and the code below is the result, but I don't think is the best way, and the regroup part isn't complete.

*Searching and Replace*

```php
// base string
$test = '<p>some bla bla bla</p>
  <p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
  <p class="normale">•bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
  <p>other bla bla bla</p>
  <p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
  <p class="normale">•bla bla and bla</p><p class="normale">&bull;bla bla and bla</p>
  <p>other bla bla bla</p>';
// First replace, I don't know but I can't find any • or &bull; with regexp
$text = str_replace(array('•', '&bull;'), '!SUB!', $text);
$regexp = '/(<p( class="normale"){0,}>(!SUB!))(.*?)<\/p>/';
// replace bulled paragraph with li tags
$text = preg_replace($regexp, "<li>$4</li>\n", $text);
```

But the part that regroup what I have found is very hard, and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: 1. if you have multiple problems then post multiple questions. 2. please re-word your question it's impossible to know what you actually want.

Comment: So... you ***want*** to generate broken HTML? (`</p>` with no `<p>` because you replaced it)

Comment: no I want to substitute all `<p>&bull;{some text}</p>` with `<li>{some text}</li>`.. damn copy paste -.-

Comment: Use an XML parser instead. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: so your's hint is to htmlentities all the bull, and parse the string in a xml parser, searching foreach paragraph that have &bull;, replacing with li and move all into a parent called ul. Writed in some words

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @Colin; however, is the above `Searching and Replace` code doing what you want? i.e. is it finding the • char? If so, I'd recommend not using the !SUB! replacement, but instead just include it as part of your

> regex:
> /(<p( class="normale")?>(&bull;|•))(.*?)</p>/

If not, then you have to find the corresponding ASCII representation(in hex or octal) and put that in its place inside the `regex.<br>`

Once you've gotten this far, an XML parser would make quick work of the reordering part of it. :-)